# Flask not importing/finding module

Tags: python, linux, flask

I am running into the most ridiculous issue(s) with Python/Flask having problems importing modules.

I have the following as my app.py.

```
import os
import logging
from flask import Flask, send_file
from flask_restful import Api
from lrsviews import Lively


app = Flask(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(filename=config.LOG_FILE, level=logging.DEBUG, format = '[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s:%(threadName)s] : %(message)s')
app.logger = createLogger(config.LOG_FILE, 'Sydwater')
api = Api(app)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5500, debug=True)
   
else:
    application = app
```

I run export FLASK_APP=app.py then run 'flask run' from the project root directory(where app.py is located) but I am faced with.

```
(ha2env) ghoul@metal:~/ha2.0> flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not import "ha2.0.app".
(ha2env) ghoul@metal:~/ha2.0>
```

What could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not import "D": FLASK\_APP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581576/could-not-import-d-flask-app)